# Using Map() method in TypeScript Angular, returning array of Observable in a function

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, observable

I have this method in my service :

```
getPriceRules(): Observable<PriceRule[]> {
   return this.http.get<PriceRule[]>(this.url)
   .map(response => PriceRule.fromJson(response));
}
```

My error :

```
Type 'Observable<PriceRule>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PriceRule[]>'.
Type 'PriceRule' is missing the following properties from type 'PriceRule[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

What I want in my `getPricesRules()` method is get all `PriceRule` that the `http.get` returns me and to apply my function `fromJson` in each `PriceRule`

```
export class PriceRule {
  public static fromJson(json: Object): PriceRule {
    return new PriceRule(
       json['id'],
       json['activity'],
       json['duration'],
       json['is_indoor'],
       json['surface'],
       json['hour_start'],
       json['hour_end'],
       json['price'],
       json['currency'],
       json['weekdays']
    );
  } 

  constructor(
        public id: string,
        public activity: string,
        public duration: number,
        public is_indoor: boolean,
        public surface: string,
        public hour_start: string,
        public hour_end: string,
        public price: number,
        public currency: string,
        public weekdays: number[]
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the Observable `map` with the array `map`:

```
.map(response => response.map((line) => PriceRule.fromJson(line));
```

The rxjs map, maps your response to another value, from there you need to take your array, and map it to the `PriceRule`.

Another way of doing this, which does not require your `fromJson` method is:

```
.map(response => response.map((line) => Object.assign(new PriceRule(), line));
```

Another way, is to make the `PriceRule` an interface, if you do that, you don't need any mapping:

```
return this.http.get<PriceRule[]>(this.url);
```

<sub>note: you should try to update to the latest rxjs >= 6 though. With that you have to use the `.pipe` function with operators</sub>

Comment: someone said that angular convert the json to an object automatically, so i don't need to do this ( fromJson) ?

Comment: @Fealo yes, it's already an object. But your fromJson also works with an object, not with json string. If you don't want any methods on your `PriceRule`, you can also make it an interface. Even less code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the map

```
.map(response => PriceRule.fromJson(response));
```

Angular HttpClient will handle that for you

Comment: but if I do that, it will returns only json objects from the server, what I want is to instantiate all the json into an Object `PriceRule` and to returns all of them ( PriceRule[])

Comment: do you use the HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'; because it does return the object

Answer (score 0):

When you say `getPriceRules(): Observable<PriceRule[]>`, what it means is the method `getPriceRules` returns Observable that will return `PricesRule[]` (price rule array). When you call map on that Observable, it tries to apply the map function to PriceRule array (PriceRule[]) and not to each PriceRule object. Also, JSON to object conversion is done by Angular automatically. So, remove the map function.